# Perl MySQL SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a Perl script accessing a MySQL db, using transactions.
I need to set the SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 on my query, but not sure how to set that option.

If I query MySQL directly, I can use a semi-colon.  ie "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1; Select ", but this does not work from Perl.

Here is the basics of my code...Not sure how/where to put the SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1

```
$dbh->do("BEGIN");          
my $sth4 = $dbh->prepare('SELECT blah blah blah');
$sth4->bind_param(1, $tmtri);
$sth4->bind_param(2, $tmyear);
$sth4->execute();
$dbh->commit();
-- do stuff
$sth4->finish();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
$dbh->do('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');
```

after connecting to the database.

Comment: Added this as the next line after the "BEGIN" statement and worked perfectly. Thanks!